# looping through the list of thumbnails and linking them to larger images using Flickr API and Jquery

Tags: jquery, flickr

I am trying to simply display some thumbnails from Flickr and link them to the larger images.
 The thumbnail portion is working, but I can't "wrap" the thumbnails with a link to the larger image.
 I got a piece of code from elsewhere that links thumbnails to their own source and that works.

```
//var url is set above https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/? bla bla

// loop through the photos
var src;
$.getJSON(url + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(json_received){
    $.each(json_received.photoset.photo, function(i,item){
        thumbnail = "https://farm"+ item.farm +".static.flickr.com/"+ item.server +"/"+ item.id +"_"+ item.secret +"_q.jpg";

        large = "https://farm"+ item.farm +".static.flickr.com/"+ item.server +"/"+ item.id +"_"+ item.secret +"_b.jpg";

        $("<img/>").attr("src", thumbnail).appendTo("#images");

        //add links - now the thumbnails are linked to themselves
        $("img").each(function() {
                 $(this).wrap("<a href='" + this.src + "'/>");
                });
    });
});
```

I tried `$(this).wrap("<a href='" + large + "'/>");` but then all the images are linked to the last large image in the list of images.
 So I have to attach the "large" value to each image somehow.
 This is about a second time I use Jquery, so bear with me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before appending to `#images` wrap the image with anchor tag and then append it.

You can use [.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) and do something like this instead

```
var $img = $("<img/>").attr("src", thumbnail);
$("<a href='" + large + "'/>").wrapInner($img).appendTo("#images");
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, just in time for the client preview too! :)